# Get the path of scraped image in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing an image **scraper** using Scrapy with default ImagePipeline.

Generally, everything has been working fine now.
However I cannot get the saved path of scraped image.

`items.py`:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name        = scrapy.Field()
    type        = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls  = scrapy.Field()
    images      = scrapy.Field()
```

`pipelines.py`:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        mage_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
           raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

`myspider.py`:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from mycrawler.items import MyItem

class VscrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """docstring for VscrawlerSpider"""
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["vesselfinder.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels?page=1"
    ]
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'vesselfinder.com/vessels\?page=[1-4]'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        ships = response.xpath('//div[@class="items"]/article')

        for ship in ships:
            item = MyItem()

            item['name'] = ship.xpath('div[2]/header/h1/a/text()').extract()[1].strip() 
            item['image_urls'] = [ship.xpath('div[1]/a/picture/img/@src').extract()[0]]
            item['type'] = ship.xpath('div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()[0]
            
            str = item['image_paths'][0] + item['type'] + item['name']

            yield item
```

I got the error:

> exceptions.KeyError: 'image_paths'.

I tried to use `item['images'][0].path` but the some error still occurs. I don't know where does this error come from?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `image_paths` field, define it:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    # ...
    image_paths = scrapy.Field()
```

<sup>You probably meant to use `images` field for it instead</sup>

Comment: I added it but the problem still remains. As I mentioned above, when I replace `image_paths` by `images` the same problem happened

Comment: @DucCuong that's probably because you have `str = item['image_paths'][0] + item['type'] + item['name']` in the spider - remove it. In other words, you are using `item['image_paths']` before it is defined.

Comment: I haved changed to `str = item['image_paths'] + item['type'] + ',' + item['name']` and run the spider again. However, the problem still remains

Comment: @DucCuong you cannot use `item['image_paths']` in the spider - it is getting set in the pipeline, later on the control flow.

Comment: OK. I got the point. So, do you know what I should do get the path of saved images?